# html5Lightbox doesn't work after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, lightbox

this script is awesome http://html5box.com/html5lightbox/, but after masonry+infinite scroll load it doesn't work...

How can I reassign click function to show lightbox window instead open image directly?
thanks

Comment: Please post you code ????

Comment: All done, simply call this

$(".html5lightbox").html5lightbox();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
$("#mydiv").load("scripts/loadimage.php",function(){
    $(".html5lightbox").html5lightbox();
});
```